# Updating SharePoint list item on preSave event causing a save conflict

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to be able to update a SharePoint listitem column that contains an XML prior SharePoint listitem events being triggered. So when the SharePoint save button is clicked, I update the XML column on preSave function, return a true in order for SharePoint update to continue, however, the code errors out with the following exception:
"Save Conflict 
         Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes."

I understand what the error means and why it's happening, I just don't know a way around. Here is a snippet of what I have in my code:

```
  function PreSaveAction() {
     updateXML();
     return true;
  }

 // Update XML based on model
function updateXML() {
    // make an ajax call here to update listitem with updated xml.
     var xml= //UpdatedXML
    var DTO = { "p_xml": xml};
           $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: "/_layouts/SharepointWebService/ePaymentService.asmx/ConvertModelToXML",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
          alert(msg.d);
          },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
 }


   [WebMethod]
    public string ConvertModelToXML(string p_xml)
    {
        try
        {
              SPUserToken saUserToken = SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
              using (SPSite ElevatedSite = new SPSite(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri, saUserToken))
        {
              using (SPWeb ElevatedWeb = ElevatedSite.OpenWeb())
                 {
                   ElevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                   SPListItem item = //Get current list item
                   item["XMLcolumn"] = p_xml;
                   item.update();
                   ElevatedWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                   return "list updated";
                 }

        }
        catch (Exception p_ex)
        {
            return "Unable to Update listitem XML: " + p_ex.Message;
        }
        return "";
    }
```

This executes but as soon as  it completes the presave call, SharePoint then attempts to do it's update, and it fails with the error mentioned above.

Is there a way I can do the update to the ListItem's XML (because I need it inside the events receiver) and still let SharePoint do it's own save (update)?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own event receiver and give it a [sequence number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.speventreceiverdefinition.sequencenumber.aspx) so that it runs before other event receivers. I know you said you needed it to run before events but perhaps it's sufficient for your use case if it runs before all *other* events.

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg749858(v=office.14).aspx :

> **Event Receiver Sequence**
>   The event receiver sequence specifies the order in which an event receiver is executed in cases where an event triggers multiple event receivers. For example, if you have two ItemAdded event receivers bound to the same list (one from Assembly "1" and the other from Assembly "2"), the event receiver that is bound with a lower sequence number is executed first. A practical example is adding an event receiver to a system list that already has a system event receiver bound to it. In that case, you assign the new event receiver a higher sequence number.

That way you can define a "synchronous before event" (like `ItemAdding`) so that it runs before other event receivers that might also modify the item, avoidng a Save Conflict.

Comment: thanks for the response. Well the reason why I need the XMl to be updated before any event receiver is I will be using that XML to populate other lists and columns, The updated xml will only be available to me on the UI, so that's what I'm trying to update the column before I reach the events, that way in the "itemupdating" event I can use the afterproperties to get the updated xml.

Comment: I see. I think `PreSaveAction` is used mostly for validation. If you want to keep client-side and server-side data in sync then one option is to hook change events for the state you care about and when they change you can update the xml column for the associated item. That avoids the two concurrent saves that happen when saving in `PreSaveAction`.

Comment: Well I should only update the XML on save, not when a change is made because there's always a chance that someone makes a change on the screen then hits cancel...